# Magento multiple selection attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, filter

Does anyone knows how I can check if an option in the multiple selection attribute is selected?

I have a example here:

[image]

For each option that is selected I want to show a image on the frontend. If Lupine is selected I want to display lupine.png, if Noten is selected I want to display noten.png and so on.

But I can't figure out how to check which one is selected.

I use the multiple selection attribute because I also want to be able to filter them on the category page.

Regards

Comment: Is this for product view page?

Comment: It's for the product view page and the category page.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the code below can be useful for your situation:

```
<?php $targetValue = explode(",", $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)); ?>

<?php  if(count($targetValue) > 0 ): ?> 
    <label><?php echo $this->__('your_attribute') ?></label>
<?php foreach($targetValues as $key=>$val): ?>
    <!-- your code here -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```