# Check if Multiselect attribute value is

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, multiselect

I have a multi select attribute with some values. I get the values with this code:

```
<?php $targetValue = explode(",", $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('nf_allergie')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)); ?>

    <?php if(count($targetValue) > 0 ): ?>
        <?php foreach($targetValue as $key=>$val): ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $key ?>">
                <span>
                    <?php echo $val ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <br>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

For example some values:
- Gluten
- Mosterd
- Noten
- Schaaldieren

How can I check if the value is **Gluten**, then show **Gluten.jpg**. And if also **Mosterd** is selected, then show also **Mosterg.jpg**

> **How can I achieve such thing?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento multiple selection attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179917/magento-multiple-selection-attribute)

Comment: Yes but the question was a little bit different, this is only for checking if a value is, then show this.

Comment: Do you want to show images instead of labels?

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Method** - Keep your images in media location or skin location in Magento, with these names.

I believe these labels are fixed.

```
<?php $targetValue = explode(",", $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('nf_allergie')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)); ?>

<?php if(count($targetValue) > 0 ): ?>
    <?php foreach($targetValue as $key=>$val): ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $key ?>">
            <span>
                <img src="skinurl/<?php echo $val ?>.jpg >
            </span>
        </div>
        <br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Another Method**  - Upload image with attribute options values.

Please read this tutorial for more details
http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/02/05/magento-add-images-to-product-attribute-options/